# Django ManyToManyField reverse Relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to do a reverse relationship on my table Tickets.

Here is my model :

```
class Tickets(models.Model):
    ticket_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticket_content = models.TextField()

class User_Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    tickets = models.ManyToManyField(Tickets, blank=True, null=True)
```

I create my ticket like that :

> ticket = Tickets.objects.create(ticket_title="test", ticket_content="test content")
>
> request.user.user_detail.tickets.add(ticket)

and the thing I'm having an issue to do is to get the username of the guy who post the ticket, (without request.user)

so I tried like that :

> ticket = Tickets.objects.get(pk=1)
>
> ticket.user_detail_set.user.username

but I get

AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'user'

Thanks you for watching, I hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you set up a many-to-many relationship, a `Ticket` may have many `User_Detail` objects. Therefore, `Ticket.user_detail_set` is a *manager*, not a single object. You *could* get the first user associated with a `Ticket` like this:

```
ticket.user_detail_set.first().user.username
```

But it sounds like you actually want a one-to-many relationship between `Ticket` and `User_Detail`, meaning you actually want `Ticket` to have a foreign key relationship. Your models should probably look like this:

```
class User_Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contents = models.TextField()
```

Then you can do:

```
ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=1)
user = ticket.user
```

You might even be able to drop the `User_Detail` model entirely, unless you use it elsewhere in your application and/or it has more fields than what is shown here.